# Graphviz Draw graph nodes using BFS order

Tags: graph, graphviz, dot

I've a graph file (.dot) with nodes that has *depth* and *size* "properties". I want to use graphviz to draw this graph considering "depth" as the depth of a Breadth First Search and the size property as a relative size of the node.

I've tried using twopi and setting all nodes that have the same depth on the same rank, but with no success. Any suggestion on how I can accomplish this?

Sample graph:

```
strict digraph  {
    root = 0;
    ranksep = 5;

{rank=same; 
0
14754221888142813049
}

{rank=same; 
17110173155996056797 
8860119836345733269  
12488214955576990298 
5164430016200693425  
6534280015544966791  
16035081712171710670 
7728255721346380016  
3065692608114503807  
15537038826989012875 
15464545769657918305 
7964210557574239786  
17237485240931079100 
9667703542183627069  
9063621412962345275  
4956992700610885217  
703599774521196210   
}

    0                    [label="A"];
    14754221888142813049 [label="B"];

    17110173155996056797 [label="C"];
     8860119836345733269 [label="D"];
    12488214955576990298 [label="E"];
     5164430016200693425 [label="F"];
     6534280015544966791 [label="G"];
    16035081712171710670 [label="H"];
     7728255721346380016 [label="I"];
     3065692608114503807 [label="J"];
    15537038826989012875 [label="K"];
    15464545769657918305 [label="L"];
     7964210557574239786 [label="M"];
    17237485240931079100 [label="N"];
     9667703542183627069 [label="O"];
     9063621412962345275 [label="P"];
     4956992700610885217 [label="Q"];
      703599774521196210 [label="R"];

    0                   -> 14754221888142813049
    0                   -> 12488214955576990298
    0                   -> 5164430016200693425 [weight=0, constraint=false];
    0                   -> 15537038826989012875
    0                   -> 7964210557574239786 
    0                   -> 9667703542183627069 
    0                   -> 17237485240931079100
    5164430016200693425 -> 8860119836345733269 [weight=0, constraint=false];
    8860119836345733269 -> 4956992700610885217 
    8860119836345733269 -> 9063621412962345275 
    8860119836345733269 -> 703599774521196210  
    8860119836345733269 -> 17110173155996056797
    8860119836345733269 -> 6534280015544966791 
    8860119836345733269 -> 16035081712171710670
    8860119836345733269 -> 7728255721346380016 
    8860119836345733269 -> 3065692608114503807 
    8860119836345733269 -> 15464545769657918305
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to capture hierarchical structure so you want to use the dot layout. By default, if you have an edge a->b, node b will be 1 level below node a. If you have a tree, and make sure the node of depth 0 appears first, you'll get the layout you want by default. If your graph is more complex, the edge criteria mentioned, or cycle breaking, may interfere with what you want. In that case, you need to make the depth constraints more explicit and turn off other edge constraints. There are several ways to do this.

Suppose you have the following graph where the numbers in the node names indicate the depth.

```
digraph {
  0 -> a1
  0 -> b1
  a1 -> a2
  a1 -> b2
  b1 -> c2
  b1 -> d2
  a2 -> d2 
  a2 -> b1 
}
```

A simple way to get what you want is to do a BFS, and set any edge not part of the BFS tree to have constraint=false.

```
digraph {
  0 -> a1
  0 -> b1
  a1 -> a2
  a1 -> b2
  b1 -> c2
  b1 -> d2
  a2 -> d2 [constraint=false]
  a2 -> b1 [constraint=false]
}
```

Or you can use rank=same to make sure nodes are placed on ranks corresponding to their depths, again turning off edges that conflict. (This assumes you have at least one chain of edges going from depth 0 to the bottom. If not, you can introduce an invisible chain of dummy nodes and edges satisfying this, and adding each dummy node to its rank=same subgraph.}

```
digraph {
  0 -> a1
  0 -> b1
  a1 -> a2
  a1 -> b2
  b1 -> c2
  b1 -> d2
  a2 -> d2 [constraint=false]
  a2 -> b1 [constraint=false]
  {rank=same a1 b1}
  {rank=same a2 b2 c2 d2}
}
```

This allows the depth function to not be actually tied to a BFS tree.

By the way, twopi should have worked, but with the layout center out instead of top down, as its levels are based on a BFS from a root node. This assumes you set the root attribute and, as you have an explicit BFS in mind, turning off non-tree edges by setting weight=0.

```
digraph {
  root=0
  0 -> a1
  0 -> b1
  a1 -> a2
  a1 -> b2
  b1 -> c2
  b1 -> d2
  a2 -> d2 [weight=0]
  a2 -> b1 [weight=0]
}
```

Comment: Hi Emden, I've edited my question adding a small sample. Could you please point what I'm doing wrong? I'm using twopi to produce the output.